# Matching different input values from different XML with a same XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on an XSLT, where I'm checking the below incoming XMLs:

Input1:

```
<URLS src="test">
<url name="1a">!#$%&'-.01=?@A[ ]^_`ab</url>
<url name="2q">4!%'-.321=?@&D[$]^_ `zs#</url></URLS>
```

Input2:

```
<URLS src="test">
<url name="1a">abXZ12</url>
<url name="2q">abXZ12uednd</url></URLS>
```

Input3:

```
<URLS src="test">
<url name="1a">qwqwqs</url>
<url name="2q">dhjekoop</url></URLS>
```

What I am doing here is,

1. Check the string length of 1a so that it falls between 2 to 30 characters and it should not have the same value as 2q.
2. If step 1 is okay then check the value of 2q so that the string length is between 4 to 30 and match the regex.
3. If step 2 is processed then it should print 1a Ok

The value of 1a or 2q may contain the below characters: 
!#$%&'-.0123456789= ?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[ SPACE ]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}

I am using the below XSLT for achieving this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions" extension-element-prefixes="regexp" exclude-result-prefixes="regexp">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="1a" select="normalize-space(/URLS/url[@name='1a']/text())" />
    <xsl:variable name="2q" select="normalize-space(/URLS/url[@name='2q']/text())" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($1a) &gt; 2 and string-length($1a) &lt;= 30 and not(regexp:test($2q, '.*^[a-z0-9A-Z\s?@`!#$%^&amp;=\[\]{_}'&apos;|.-}]+$.*', 'gi') )">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string-length($2q) &gt; 4 and string-length($2q) &lt; 30 and (regexp:test($2q, '.*^[a-z0-9A-Z\s?@`!#$%^&amp;=\[\]{_}'&apos;|.-}]+$.*', 'gi') )">
                    <xsl:element name="status">2q Ok</xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:element name="status">terminate for 2q disallowed length</xsl:element>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:element name="status">1a Ok</xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="status">terminate for 1a disallowed length</xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This XSLT almost works, only thing is I am not able to match the regex properly. Any help in this will be really helpful.

Comment: "*I am not able to match the regex properly.*" Not sure what that means. Also, which XSLT processor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be problems with your regular expressions.  The relevant part of what you're using is this (non-regex predicates removed):

```
<xsl:when test="regexp:test($2q, '.*^[a-z0-9A-Z\s?@`!#$%^&amp;=\[\]{_}'&apos;|.-}]+$.*', 'gi')">
```

In the first place, be aware that entity references in the values of stylesheet attributes are processed when the stylesheet tree is built, so the function call expression conveyed by that attribute is this:

```
regexp:test($2q, '.*^[a-z0-9A-Z\s?@`!#$%^&=\[\]{_}''|.-}]+$.*', 'gi')
```

There are several things to observe about that:

- the regex string is not a well-formed XPath string literal as a result of being apostrophe-delimited but having two literal apostrophes appearing inside.
- the leading and trailing `.*` are useless, because between them you are anchoring the the rest of the pattern to the beginning and end of the input
- the 'g' flag is irrelevant to this function, and the 'i' isn't doing anything for you because you've accounted for both upper- and lowercase letters directly in the regex.

Furthermore, the first alternative of the outer `xsl-choose` is taken only when the value of `$2q` *does not* match the regex, so it will never be the case that the test within that alternative will find that the same variable then *does* match the same regex.  It appears that you don't want the first test at all.

Among those, it is probably the quoting problem that is trickiest, but in this particular case you should be able to address it by inverting quote styles.  This variation retains the structure of your stylesheet, but addresses all of those issues:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
    extension-element-prefixes="regexp"
    exclude-result-prefixes="regexp">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="1a" select="normalize-space(/URLS/url[@name='1a'])" />
  <xsl:variable name="2q" select="normalize-space(/URLS/url[@name='2q'])" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="string-length($1a) &gt; 2 and string-length($1a) &lt;= 30">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test='string-length($2q) &gt; 4 and string-length($2q) &lt; 30 and regexp:test($2q, "^[a-z0-9A-Z\s?@`!#$%^&amp;=\[\]{_}&apos;|.-]+$")'>
          <xsl:element name="status">2q Ok</xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:element name="status">terminate for 2q disallowed length</xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:element name="status">1a Ok</xsl:element>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:element name="status">terminate for 1a disallowed length</xsl:element>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```